# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing numpy_ops: The specified module could not be found. when importing spacy in Python

Tags: python, spacy, importerror

I was trying to import spaCy because I wanted to remove stop words.
When I tried running the import line, it gave me the error mentioned in the title.

I had installed `spacy` using

```
python -m pip install spacy
```

because `pip install spacy` gave me an error saying:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\nikun\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\nikun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install spacy': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How do I fix this so that it imports spacy without error?
I would appreciate any help and am new to coding so please forgive for any silly errors I am making.

Comment: How did you install python? If you've done that properly, add the path `python.exe` path to your environment variables. Then type `python -m ensurepip` on `cmd` to check if you have `pip` and `setuptools`.

Comment: Both pip and setuptools are there. python.exe added to environment variable. still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run the following line on the command prompt:

> python -m pip install msvc-runtime

Then the error goes away